# DOXFX using Application Insights end-user user analytics

Tags: azure-application-insights, docfx

How can you add Application insights end-user user analytics to DocFx to track the usage of every documentation page?

The Application Insights documentation states you need to insert the JavaScript snippet listed below immediately before the closing  tag, but I'm not sure if this is possible in DocFx or the best way to accomplish.

Would you need a postprocessor, or could you use a custom template?

```
<!-- 
To collect end-user usage analytics about your application, 
insert the following script into each page you want to track.
Place this code immediately before the closing </head> tag,
and before any other scripts. Your first data will appear 
automatically in just a few seconds.
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config){
    function i(config){t[config]=function(){var 
i=arguments;t.queue.push(function(){t[config].apply(t,i)})}}var t={config:config},u=document,e=window,o="script",s="AuthenticatedUserContext",h="start",c="stop",l="Track",a=l+"Event",v=l+"Page",y=u.createElement(o),r,f;y.src=config.url||"https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js";u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(y);try{t.cookie=u.cookie}catch(p){}for(t.queue=[],t.version="1.0",r=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace","Dependency"];r.length;)i("track"+r.pop());return i("set"+s),i("clear"+s),i(h+a),i(c+a),i(h+v),i(c+v),i("flush"),config.disableExceptionTracking||(r="onerror",i("_"+r),f=e[r],e[r]=function(config,i,u,e,o){var s=f&&f(config,i,u,e,o);return s!==!0&&t["_"+r](config,i,u,e,o),s}),t
    }({
        instrumentationKey:"###-###-###-##"
    });

    window.appInsights=appInsights;
    appInsights.trackPageView();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

No PostProcessor is needed. You can achieve this by customizing the template. More information can be found in [official tutorial](http://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/howto_create_custom_template.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066279/how-can-i-customize-docfx-documentation-themes-or-templates/37361779#37361779). You can add your code in `partials/head.tmpl.partial`. It will affect all the generated page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will give this a try. wasn't aware of the use of partials/head.tmpl.partial